# Mybatis:log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory)

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, mybatis

In my java web application I used Mybatis for mapping.
Before few minutes I didn't have this problem, I don't know what hapened, please help me.

```
Grave:   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory).
Grave:   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Grave:   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mybatis uses log system as following priorities:

1. slf4j
2. commons-logging
3. log4j2
4. log4j
5. jdk-logging
6. no-logging

The warning you published means there was no proper appender for log4j found. This could be occur in two circumstances:

1. there was no log4j configuration found, which usually named 'log4j.properties', see [log4j2 configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html);
2. there was no any appender defined in log4j configuration;

If this warning happened as you described, a few minutes ago it was ok, that was impossible if you've changed nothing.

The probably reason was the dependencies had been changed and some of these log implementations ware replaced or just been removed.

For example, if slf4j and logback were there, your application should use slf4j without any warning, however, if they were not there, log4j2 or log4j shoud be used. This time warning occured cause you had defined no log4j configuration properly.

So, if you are going to use slf4j with logback, you could just remove dependency of log4j or log4j2. Otherwise, if you are really want to use log4j or log4j2, you need remove dependencies of slf4j and commongs-logging and add proper log4j configuration. The log4j2 configuration documents are listed [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).